# Get the particular date date from Postgresql database through python

Tags: python, postgresql

I would like to get the yesterda's date data from postgresql database through python . I have tried

```
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE login_time > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day)")
```

I am able to get yesterday data as well today date data but i wanted only yesterday's data. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:
      It might help you.

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Date('login_time') = "2016-03-12")

or if you pass variable then,

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Date('login_time') = "+ dateVariable + ")

Answer (score 0):

You did not write what type is `login_time`.

If it's `Time Stamp` use:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE login_time::date = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
```

If it's `Date` use:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE login_time = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
```